# where to find MyDataBase.BAK file on SQL server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008

where to find MyDataBase.BAK file on SQL server 2008 ?

and how i can restore this file to my DataBase ?

thank's in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you back it up using SQL only without specifing a full path, e.g.

```
BACKUP DATABASE MyDataBase TO DISK='MyDataBase.BAK'
GO
```

I think by default your backup will get placed in the Backup folder in the SQL Server install, i.e. `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup` or similar. You can restore it using

```
RESTORE DATABASE MyDataBase FROM DISK='MyDataBase.BAK'
GO
```

but if the orginal files are still there you'll need to specify alternate paths for the restore, e.g.

```
RESTORE DATABASE MyDataBaseTestRestore FROM DISK='MyDataBase.BAK'
WITH MOVE 'MyDataBase' TO 'C:\Temp\TestRestore.mdf',
     MOVE 'MyDataBase_Log' TO 'C:\Temp\TestRestore_log.ldf'
GO
```

but it's so much simpler if you use management studio for all of this stuff.